# How Do I use redirect and pass an object to the edit action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, action

**How Do I use redirect and pass an object to the edit action?** The following code does not work:

```
  def edit
    @promotion = Promotion.find_by_id(@params['promo_id']) 
  end

  def update
    promotion = Promotion.find(params[:promotion_profile][:promotion_id])
       promo_perfil = promotion.profile

       if promo_perfil.update_attributes(params[:promotion_profile])

         redirect_to admin_edit_path(promotion.id => @params[:promo_id])
       else
   end
```

Comment: you asked somehow the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865452/how-do-you-use-redirect-to-when-the-action-is-dependent-on-a-parameter-being-pass I'm still awaiting you accept or comment my answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The edit action is looking for `params['promo_id']` (why `@params['promo_id']`?).

So pass `:promo_id` this way:

```
redirect_to admin_edit_path(:promo_id => promotion)
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't redirect in this case just: `render :action => :edit`

This is standard Rails behaviour, you will see this in all scaffolded controllers as a way of re rendering the edit form with the current object in the update action without having to rely on stuffing objects into cookies to pass around.